# How can we implement page up and page down functionality in custom table of LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, html

We have a custom table in LWC. We have a requirement if the user is at the top of the table (i.e at row 1) if he wants to see last record in table, there must be page down/up button with the help of it user will move directly at the bottom of the table(i.e at the last row). and if user is at last row then on click of that button he should move up directly at first row. we have a scroll bar that helps to scroll record by record. additionally we want this functionality.

```
HTML:
<template>
<div>
<table  class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_bordered slds-table_striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>                     
            <th>
                <a data-id="Name" onclick={sort}>
                    <div>Name
                        <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:arrowup" size="x-small" if:true={nameUpBool}></lightning-icon>
                        <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:arrowdown" size="x-small" if:true={nameDWBool}></lightning-icon>
                    </div>
                    
                </a>
            </th>
            <th>
                <a data-id="Industry" onclick={sort}>
                    <div>Industry
                        <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:arrowup" size="x-small" if:true={ageUpBool}></lightning-icon>
                        <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:arrowdown" size="x-small" if:true={ageDWBool}></lightning-icon>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </th>
            <th>
                <div>AccountNumber</div>    
            </th>
            <th>
                <div>Rating</div>                            
            </th>
                <th>
                    <div>type</div>                        
            </th>
                <th>
                    <div>Phone</div>                        
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <template for:each={accountData} for:item="person">
            <tr class={person.rowSelected} key={person.Id} data-id={person.Id}>                
                <td key={person.Id}>                                
                    {person.Name}
                </td>
                <td key={person.Id}>
                    {person.Industry}
                </td>
                <td key={person.Id}>
                    {person.AccountNumber}
                </td>
                <td key={person.Id}>
                    {person.Rating}
                </td> 
                    <td key={person.Id}>
                    {person.type}
                </td>
                <td key={person.Id}>
                    {person.Phone}
                </td> 
            </tr>                                                                     
        </template>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

```
JS:
@track accountData = [];
@wire(fetchAccounts)
wiredData({ error, data }) {
  if (data) {
    this.accountData=data;
    console.log('Data===' +JSON.stringify(this.accountData));
  } else if (error) {
    console.error('Error:'+error);
  }
}

sortedDirection = 'asc';
sortedColumn;

nameUpBool;
nameDWBool;
ageUpBool;
ageDWBool;
sort(e) {
    this.nameUpBool = false;
    this.nameDWBool = false;
    this.ageUpBool = false;
    this.ageDWBool = false;

    let colName =e.currentTarget.dataset.id;
    console.log( 'Column Name is===' + colName );

    if(this.sortedColumn === e.currentTarget.dataset.id){
        this.sortedDirection = this.sortedDirection === 'asc' ? 'desc' : 'asc';
    }else{
        this.sortedDirection = 'asc';
    } 

    let reverse = this.sortedDirection === 'asc' ? 1 : -1;

    switch (colName) {

        case "Name":
        if ( this.sortedDirection == 'asc' ){
            this.nameUpBool = true;
            console.log('IN IF OF SWITCH');
        }  
        else{
            this.nameDWBool = true;
        }     
        break;

        case "Industry":
        if ( this.sortedDirection == 'asc' ){
            this.ageUpBool = true;
            console.log('IN IF OF SWITCH Industry***');
        }  
        else{
            this.ageDWBool = true;
        }     
        break;


    }

    
    let table = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.accountData));
    table.sort((a,b) => {return a[e.currentTarget.dataset.id] > b[e.currentTarget.dataset.id] ? 1 * reverse : -1 * reverse});
    this.sortedColumn = e.currentTarget.dataset.id;        
    this.accountData = table;

}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What part of it isn't working? Please edit your question with more details, including the code you've already written, and detailed information about what part isn't working.

Comment: I have mentioned my code for table. but I was not get how to implement that page up and down functionality in table.

Comment: You are giving class={person.rowSelected}  class to your row. Based on last row value whatever value of person.rowSelected use this. Or you can add class to your last row in your data. Thats not tricky

Answer (score 0):

I have added a demo of how you can scroll to bottom and to the top. You need to give class to the table and class to the last row of your table. Based on these class you can scroll to top and bottom.

Check out a [demo](https://studio.webcomponents.dev/edit/Ms5Xjk6fsss4hgyKUWTa/src/app.html?p=stories) code.

Comment: Thanks @darkshadowrule for your reply.. but in my code row are dynamic..

Comment: You are giving class={person.rowSelected} class to your row. Based on last row value whatever value of person.rowSelected use this. Or you can add class to your last row in your data. Thats not tricky

Comment: I was used that class but not worked. and how can we add the class for last row becoz the row are dynamic

Comment: top button is working but not a down

Comment: Iterate on your data and check if it is last row of data add a attribute data.className = "lastRow". And use this in your tr